# DSS - Insert Parent Child tables

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

Im trying to create a DSS service that can insert Order / Order details data.

It looks like standard task so I guessing there should be some 'best practice solution'

So in transaction mode insert new row in parent table, get a new row ID and send it in insert statement for populating child table... In a case of failure roll back the whole transaction ..

Can someone suggest where should I start or point to some resources ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can user [Query Result Export feature](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/Query+Result+Export+Sample) to export the rowID after querying a select query to get the rowID and pass that to populate child tables